# Difference between GridView and Grid

Tags: wpf, xaml

Can anyone tell me the difference between GridView and a Grid in WPF XAML?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple explanation would be
**Grid**
If you have just a single item with no repetitive subitem design then a grid is used. If the number of subitems are fixed
**GridView**
If you have a repetitive design like collection and you dont know the number of items that can be present then a gridview is used instead.
You can find more details on msdn forums.

Answer (score 9):

Here are the details for UWP. Should be similar for WPF I think.

**Grid** - used for defining layouts and formatting or static information. It is one of the several "layout panels" that are available (others include: RelativePanel, StackPanel, VariableSizedWrapGrid, and Canvas). Grid does not have an `ItemSource` member to dynamically display items by binding. Grid does have `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` attached properties (i.e. that can be used on other controls) to position them within the Grid.

Sample Code:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutPanel1" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" 
      Margin="20"
      BorderBrush="{StaticResource Page_Brush}"
      BorderThickness="1 1 1 1">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="44"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

</Grid>
```

More Information: [Grid Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid), [Layout Panels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/layout-panels)

---

**GridView** - used for displaying a set or collection of data (i.e. dynamic number of items). Another control available to display a set or collection of data is a ListView. One way to use this is by setting `ItemSource` (i.e. binding). By default, a data item is displayed in the GridView as the string representation of the data object it's bound to. To specify exactly how items in the GridView are displayed, you create a `DataTemplate` to define the layout of controls used to display an individual item. The controls in the layout can be bound to properties of a data object, or have content defined inline. You assign the `DataTemplate` to the `ItemTemplate` property of the GridView. The `DataTemplate` can contain a Grid (or any of the other layout panels mentioned above) to specify the layout of controls of an individual item.

Sample Code:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyItems}"
          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
          ItemClick="GridView_ItemClick"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyItemTemplate}"
          BorderBrush="{StaticResource MyItemBrush}" 
          BorderThickness="1 1 1 1"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
/>
```

More Information: [GridView Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview), [List view and Grid view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/listview-and-gridview), [Guidelines for list view and grid view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465465.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

From what I see Grid is more like a table, each row contains the same number of items (one for each column) no matter the size of the window.

GridView looks like a table but if you reduce the width of the window, the items from one row will jump on the next row:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Both of your images refer to `GridView`, I assume that is a mistake and the second should be `Grid`

Comment: @yoelhalb No, I was just showing what happens with the items when you change the width of the window: with GridView the items change places, they don't stay on the same column and row; with Grid they do stay on the same column and row.